# MS SQL Server Copy Relational Data Between Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We have a database in MS SQL Server 2005 (actually development database), which hosts many relational tables holding working space of an application. Using this application user can define many new data structures each are stored as rows in different tables and a column named 'finalised' of type bit indicates that the set of data copied to another database (which acts a release db with only finalised data) which exactly has the same schema with development database.

As the user finishes his work, he starts a synchronisation process for a set of data (whose finalised field is not set to 1 yet) and after performing a few validation rules, if everything seems to OK, we will copy this set to release database and mark finalised field of related tables as 1 in the development database. Is there a simple mechanism that we can use rather than selecting data from the first db and inserting it to destination programmatically? There are too many tables to select from and these tables actually holds relational data which are connected on id values.

The release db mostly seems to have views of tables from source database with condition 'where finalised = 1', but we should also add a set when the user starts synchronisation for a data set, while the finalised field is still 0 (if the validation process is OK).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL script (stored proc) to promote these new table entries is likely your best option in this scenario.

Some alternatives would be:

Inserting the dev identities into production tables -- which is risky if data can be inserted via any other method.  It's also worth considering table locks that occur when identity inserts are enabled -- your end users would likely be unable to query the production tables while this is running.  This can be done with the syntax:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [myTABLE] ON
INSERT INTO PROD.DBO.myTABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3)
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM DEV.DBO.myTABLE WHERE...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [myTABLE] OFF
```

Here is a KB on this.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

Another option would be filtered replication from dev to prod -- again, this would only work if there is no other means of inserting the data into production, and also holds additional risk factors if the dev entries can be altered after they are flagged as approved - as the changes would immediately replicate to production, potentially impacting end users.  Your production tables would NOT be modifiable in this instance.

Here is a KB on filtered replication: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146925(v=sql.105).aspx

Ideally, a production environment is isolated completely from a development environment -- which means the options I just suggested would NOT be used -- but I presented them as FYIs.

That said, assuming your table schema's are identical, you could look at adding a new identity column in production, thus allowing you to insert the dev id along side it.

ie:

```
dev.dbo.myTable
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
val1 int,
val2 int,
flag bit

prod.dbo.myTable
newid int identity(1,1) primary key, -- new column in prod
id int,
val1 int,
val2 int,
flag bit
```

You would need to add a new identity to each production table, so every production table would hold the dev id... and your front end code would remain unchanged.  This would be my approach if schema changes were an option.

This would allow you to do a straight insert from dev to prod, keeping the dev id's intact, and also providing a method of matching prod back to dev at the same time.

Hope this helps.